# How to hide popup.html in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Here is my setup and i am trying to figure out if its possible.
I have an Chrome Extension which goes and parses some data from a active page and then copys the result to the clipboard. My popup.html is minimal and looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style=''>
<head>
<script src='popup.js'></script>
</head>
<body style="width:600px;">
<textarea id="emailphone" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="copy-to-clipboard">Copy to Clipboard</button>
</body>
</html>
```

What i would like to do is actually not even show the popup at all as my script goes and creates an Alert and displays the data. But for one my script sets the Inner Html of the emailphone textarea with the parsed data and then i go and copy the textarea to my clipboard. Here is my popup script

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    if (request.action == "getSource") {
      emailphone.innerText = request.source;
      myFunction();

    }
  });
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("copy-to-clipboard").addEventListener("click", copytoclipboard);
  });

  function onWindowLoad() {

    var message = document.querySelector('#emailphone');

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
      file: "getPagesSource.js"
    }, function() {
      // If you try and inject into an extensions page or the webstore/NTP you'll get an error
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        emailphone.innerText = 'There was an error injecting script : \n' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message;
      }
    });

  }
  function copytoclipboard() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("emailphone");
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert(copyText.value);
  }

  window.onload = onWindowLoad;
```

when i use window.close() it only closes after i close the alert. So what i am looking for is to only show the Alert and not the popup.html

Comment: Sounds like you don't need the popup at all, just the alert. In that case remove "default_popup" from manifest.json, declare a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) and use chrome.browserAction.onClicked listener ([examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:browseraction)). Since the background script runs in a hidden background page you will need to create the textarea element manually by using document.createElement and appendChild.

Comment: Is there somewhere a good example how to create a element and appendchild ? Also how do I access the pack ground page afterwards ?

Comment: 1) Examples should be trivial to find using google search (or bing). 2) I don't understand what you mean but it sounds like a separate question not related to the task. Hopefully you'll find all answers in the documentation I've linked.